# How to delete the item on the click of the button in every item?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to Html and ASP.Net MVC. 
I want to make the view looks like this:

[image: One item one delete button]

**each item will be deleted when each button is on click**

And here are my simple codes

```
@using ControllerPractice.Models
@model IEnumerable<Table>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index , Data amounts @Model.Count()</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var t in Model)
    {
        <li><h2>@t.Title</h2></li>
        <li>@t.Text</li>
        using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home"))
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="Id" value=@t.Id />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        }
    }
</ul>


<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Home"))
    {
        <p>
            Title: <input type="text" name="Title">
            Content: <input type="text" name="Text">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </p>
    }
</div>
<div>

</div>
```

and my **API**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int? Id)
        {
            db.Table.Remove(db.Table.Find(Id));
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View("Index", db.Table.ToList());
        }
```

> **I'm wondering is there any better solution instead of using  <input type="hidden" / >** ? 
>   **Or how to put the form outside of the 'ul' tag ?**
>   **Please improve my codes , thanks**.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using hidden inputs. And you can move the form by... moving the Html.BeginForm call to where you want it to start, taking care to close the tags properly. If you hit more specific problems you're welcome to ask more questions, but 'improve my codes' isn't really something we can debug.

Comment: You can add the `id` as a route value - `using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home" new { id = t.Id })) { <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> }`

Comment: Thanks ! :) ! Helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use HttpPost for Delete method, so there is nothing wrong when using hidden field to store submit parameters.
But you could move the form to outside of the 'ul' tag by updating your code like this.

Razor code

```
<h2>Index , Data amounts @Model.Count()</h2>
using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Home"))
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var t in Model)
        {
            <li><h2>@t.Title</h2></li>
            <li>@t.Text</li>
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="" />
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="setDeletedId('@t.Id')" />
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Javascript

```
function setDeletedId(deletedId) {
   var hidden = document.getElementById("Id");
   hidden.value = deletedId;
}
```

Another method is updating your Delete method to HttpGet and using Html.ActionLink

Razor code

```
<h2>Index , Data amounts @Model.Count()</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (var t in Model)
    {
        <li><h2>@t.Title</h2></li>
        <li>@t.Text</li>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Home", new {id = "@t.Id"}, null)%>
    }
</ul>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete(int? Id)
{
    db.Table.Remove(db.Table.Find(Id));
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View("Index", db.Table.ToList());
}
```